# keep getting this error{relation "profiles_user" does not exist}

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am a beginner programmer working on my own project on Django. I am trying to make a model create itself whenever a user is created. but i keep getting this error {relation "profiles_user" does not exist}.
I am using PostgreSQL as my DB. Btw this Error occurs when I try to migrate data

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_expert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)







EDUCATION=(
    ('Collage','Collage'),
    ('Post_Graduate','Post_Graduate'),
    ('Masters','Masters'),
    ('PHD','PHD'),
)


class Expert(models.Model):
    expert = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    discription = models.TextField(null=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EDUCATION,  null=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    experience = models.TextField(null=True)
    charge_per_hour = models.IntegerField(default="0")

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}')



def create_profile(sender,**kwargs ):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile=Expert.objects.create(expert=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Did you `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Does this code still work if you remove the signal receiver? My suspicion is the bug doesn't originate there, but perhaps in your views

Comment: yeah, the problem occurs when I try to migrate data. and yes it still when I remove the signals

Comment: Delete all your migration files and then again do makemigrations and migrate

Comment: already done that and even created a new DB still nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem that I need to specifically makemigration the app it self.

```
python manage.py makemigrations profiles
python manage.py migrate profiles
```